# kendo jquery graph value axis configuration options

Tags: jquery, graph, kendo-chart

I'm generating a graph for last 6 months, and months will come from Datasource, how can I display month names in Value axis by reading from datasource as they are dynamic?

```
function initKendo() {
    var params = { sysCountryCD: 'USA', webID: 493, SubjectID: '10000001'};
    var data = callWebService("GetStudentProgress", params, false);
    //alert(data);
    $("#column-chart").kendoChart({
        series: [{
            name: "Series 1",
            type: "bar",
            data: data,
            field: "worksheetUsed",
            color: "#05347A"
        }],
        categoryAxis: {
            field: "reportingMonth"
        },
        valueAxis: [{
            name: "Month",
            labels: {
                format: "{0}"
            }
        }],
            title: {
                text: "Worksheets used"
            },
            legend: {
                visible: false
            }
  });
}
```

In datasource, I have 'Month' column which returns 3 letter month codes like Jan, Feb, Mar etc.